# Moddb/Gamejolt alternative for tabletop games

Tags: game-design, game-development

When designing (any kind of) a game it is best to have feedback from as many people as possible. Since testing with friends may not be reliable enough (they are biased and don't want to hurt your feelings) and also probably none of them will be testing your game on their own with their friends, is there any kind of dedicated internet server, where you can put your game for others to test it as well as test creations of others?

I have noticed that some people put their game at BGG but I haven't found there any dedicated category for it.

Comment: One recent example that comes to mind is the "GenCant" *event* on Twitter, where a "roll and write" contest took place. There were something like 70 unique games that came about, and most of them are available to be printed and played.

Comment: I have found both webpage http://www.gencant.com/ and a twitter page https://twitter.com/GenCant but both are bit of a mess, I can't really find anything else than Welcome to Dino World

Comment: Indeed, it would have been a lot easier to find these games back in August

Comment: Anyone can create content for [Tabletop Simulator](http://berserk-games.com/tabletop-simulator/). It's a very mature product, but it's not free.

Comment: I've seen Kickstarter compaigns that provided the game via [Tabletopia](https://tabletopia.com/) so potential backers could "try before you buy". The advantage of Tabletopia is that you don't have to pay for the app (and the game can be made free too). I don't know what the procedure is to get a game unto Tabletopia.